# Problems with staggered merged table cells

Tags: html, merge, html-table

I'm trying to create a table layout like this:

```
A  B
C  B
C  D
```

In pseudocode:

```
<tr><td id='A'/><td id='B' rowspan=2/></tr>
<tr><td id='C' rowspan=2/><td id='D'/></tr>
```

However this code displays Cell 'D' as a ghost cell like this:

```
A  B
C  B D
C
```

If I try:

```
<tr><td id='A'/><td id='B' rowspan=2/></tr>
<tr><td id='C' rowspan=2/></tr>
<tr><td id='D'/></tr>
```

I get this:

```
A  B
A  B
C  D
C  D
```

I'd be really grateful is someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: "I'm trying to create a table layout" - Don't use tables for layout

Comment: @Eric, I assume they meant a table _with a_ layout like this.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, but you've got to ask yourself why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWMuR/) with no problems:

```
<table>
   <tr><td id='A'>A</td><td id='B' rowspan='2'>B</td></tr>
   <tr><td id='C' rowspan='2'></td></tr>
   <tr><td id='D'>D</td></tr>
</table>
```

I added two divs and show table rules so you can see that it works

Comment: Thanks heaps guys, this has ended a lot of frustration. I feel kinda stupid now though...